# How to load data to the layouts in background to load the activity faster?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my app I have horizontally scroll with nested Linear layouts and based upon the button (5 buttons) pressed by user I need to show different contents in that row (texts, images, stickers, etc).I decided to load all contents to these layouts in onCreate itself and based upon on the button clicked I ll make visible the desired layout and hide the remaining. This is working perfectly but taking 3 seconds to load the activity. when I tried to load these contents in Threads or Asynctask the activity is loading faster but the contents are loading only after 15 seconds. I don't know what else to try. Please guide me what else I can try. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post code and screenshot to help you better.

Comment: try to add code and explain clearly what u are doing.

Comment: AsyncTask loads items sequentially, it queues them on a WorkerThread and will load them sequentally. Why not use Java's `ExecutorFramework` i.e `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` to give work to separate threads to handle. That should reduce your load times. But yes, we would like some code!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like u are doing too much operations on UI thread which u should not do. In such cases UI lags.
Solution for your problem is to use

```
Async task
```

Or `Handler`

Async Task has 4 methods:
`onPreExecute()`,
`doInBackground()`,
`onProcessUpdate()` and

```
onPostExecute()
```

Where `doInBackground()` is most imp method to do task in background

**note**: for Handler, just make sure that when you finish ur background task, use `runOnUiThread` to handle UI components